# How to plot a 2D plane of set area, using a point on a plane and a normal vector, in 3D space, using plotly and dash?

Tags: python, plotly, linear-algebra, plotly-dash, plane

I would like to plot a 2d plane of a set area (e.g. 10x10 square or 5dia cicle) in 3D space using plotly so I can include it in my dash app. I would also like to be able to rotate and position the plane in 3D space using a point on the plane (in the centre of the plane) and a normal vector to the plane (i.e. a line joining a point in space and the point on the plane).

I have tried using np.meshgrid to create an xy grid and then used linear algebra equation of a plane to calculate z points. I then used figure.add_surface(x,y,z) to plot the plane.

To get meshgrid, I used the point in the centre of the plane and added 'spread' to its x and y coordinates in positive and negative directions.

```
#Point in space
x_iso = 10
y_iso = 10
z_iso = 10

#Point in the centre of the required plane
x_pt = 50
y_pt = 50
z_pt = 50

#Components of the plane equation 
delta_x = x_pt - x_iso
delta_y = y_pt - y_iso
delta_z = z_pt - z_iso

#Spread for xy mesh
spread = 10 

#Creating x,y mesh
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(x_pt-spread, x_pt+spread), np.linspace(y_pt-spread, y_pt+spread))

#Calculating corresponding z of the xy mesh using linear algebra equation of a plane using a point and a normal vector
zz = ( delta_x*x_pt + delta_y*y_pt + delta_z*z_pt - delta_x*xx - delta_y*yy ) / delta_z


CT_figure.add_surface(x=xx,y=yy,z=zz,showscale=False,showlegend=False)
```

This method works and plots a plane in 3D. The issue is that the area of the plane depends on the xy mesh and the angle orientation of the plane relative to xy plane.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyWa4.jpg

For a plane almost parallel to z axis, even for small spread in x or y the plane stretches out a lot in the z direction due to its angle. Also if the plane is parallel to an axis one of the delta_x,y,z is zero and in the case of z plane it becomes infinite.

I need to be able to set the area and shape of the plane and then rotate it in space using the point in the middle of the plane and a random point in space which creates a normal vector to the plane when joined to the point on the plane.

EDIT:
I have come to another solution which is to generate a plane in x,y plane of the required shape and break it down into points (x,y,z) where z is just a height off the xy plane. 
Then I perform a point rotation by the required angles for all points on that plane. Seems to work fine, and I'm currently cleaning up the code and then going to try implement it into its required use. I will post an update once finished. Still open for other suggestions!

Comment: You will need to add the spread in the direction of the plane not in the <x,y> direction. Some of the component of the spread you want is in the z direction.

Comment: @JonGuiton I tried doing that but resolving spread components with two angles into x,y,z coordinates is quite complex and I was wondering if there was an easier way to do it.